# update textbox when paragraph changes value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate a textbox with the value of a paragraph element when the

value changes.  I am using jquery.  When the text in

changes, nothing happens.  Below is my jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#textbit').change(function(){
    var isbn = $('#textbit').val();
    alert(isbn);
    $('#ISBN').val(isbn);
});
});
```

Comment: is the alert is shown? what is the html code for this?

Comment: You need to use `.text()` for non form elements. IE, `.text()` for `<p>` and `.val()` for `<input>`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textbit').change(function(){
        var isbn = $('#textbit').text();
        $('#ISBN').val(isbn);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If $('#ISBN') is not an input element it should go with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#textbit').change(function(){
    var isbn = $('#textbit').val(); //val for input elements
    $('#ISBN').text(isbn);  // text for the rest
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update textarea when paragraph value changes

Not exactly sure if this is what you are trying to do. But you could try something like this.

**Example HTML:**

```
<h3>Type in Blue area</h3>
<p contenteditable="true"></p>
<textarea></textarea>
```

**JS:**

```
$('p').keyup(function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    var val = String.fromCharCode(key);

    $('textarea').append(val);
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/8m2vk83x/30/